# Are there any PS3 Backwards Compatible Fighting Sticks?

Tags: ps3, controllers

I have a 60 GB PS3 that can play Playstation 2 games.  Are there any fighting sticks for the Playstation 3 that will work with PS2 fighting games?  If so, are there any that absolutely will not work?

Edit:

Shoryuken forums advise the following for mid-range PS3 sticks: "PS3 owners, get either the HRAP3: SA or the Mad Catz TE. If backwards compatibility is important to you, get a HRAP:SA."

Does that mean the Mad Catz TE doesn't support backwards compatibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mad Catz sticks are NOT backwards compatible with PS2 games, Sony won't release the code to allow them to be backwards compatible. Unless something has changed in the last 2-3 months (cant find any changes so the info should be accurate). So your best bet is HRAP.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had any trouble getting my PS3 controllers working on my PS2 games. The problems I've had have been getting my PS2 controllers working on my PS3, but I haven't tried the SFIV sticks.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm specifically asking about fighting sticks, not regular controllers.

Comment: @Christian Any PS3 controller (including fighting sticks) should work.

Comment: Can you confirm this?  Specifically with the Mad Catz TE stick?

Comment: @christian I don't have that stick.